# R: Network visualization from data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I am a newbie in R-programming. I face the following problem:

I have a `data.frame` giving the conccurence of words in paragraphs. 
I also have a subset of this `data.frame` giving the conccurences only for one specific word, here `kris`. [image: screenshot]

I want to visualize this as a network. In a first step, just for one term, in the second step maybe with more vertices and edges. [image: Network]

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with packages that I can use in R-Studio, such as `igraph` or `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df <- data.frame("kris"=1:3, row.names = c("foo", "bar", "hotel"))
df$word <- rownames(df)
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(reshape2::melt(df, ncol(df)))
plot(g, edge.width=E(g)$value, vertex.color=(degree(g, mode = "out")==0) + 1L)
```

as a starter.